# Angular4 apply multiple attribute on single condition on an html element

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I want a radio button checked and readonly if a condition is satisfied.
There are many variables I need to check.
This is my code,
`data` and `rated_data` are two arrays.

```
<input type = "radio" value = "5" [checked] = "rated_data[i]!== undefined && rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id !== undefined && rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id == data.psf_master_id && 5 == rated_data[i].spr_review" formControlName = "{{data.psf_master_id}}" ngModel required>
```

What i want is something like this:

```
<input type = "radio" value = "5" [checked][disabled] = "rated_data[i]!== undefined && rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id !== undefined && rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id == data.psf_master_id && 5 == rated_data[i].spr_review" formControlName = "{{data.psf_master_id}}" ngModel required>
```

Is this possible..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fonction :

```
isCheckedAndDisabled(i: number) {
  return this.rated_data[i]!== undefined && 
  this.rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id !== undefined &&
  this.rated_data[i].spr_psf_master_id == data.psf_master_id &&
  5 == this.rated_data[i].spr_review;
}


<input type = "radio" value = "5" [checked]="isCheckedAndDisabled(i)" [disabled]="isCheckedAndDisabled(i)" formControlName = "{{data.psf_master_id}}" ngModel required>
```